# Remove data from disabled input

Tags: grails

I have a field that i disabled in html and sent a request through ajax to a controller, the field doesn't come with request, but it's still present in the bean.

How can i managed to remove it automatically from the bean?

SimpleController

```
 def update(ConfiguracaoSistema configuracaoSistemaInstance) {
    if (configuracaoSistemaInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (configuracaoSistemaInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond configuracaoSistemaInstance.errors, view: 'index'
        return
    }

    configuracaoSistemaInstance.save flush: true

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'configuracaoSistema.label', default: 'ConfiguracaoSistema'), ''])
            redirect action: "index"
        }
        '*' { respond configuracaoSistemaInstance, [status: OK] }
    }
}
```

In gsp i have a field that i 'll disable with jquery

```
<g:textField name="enderecoServicosCatix" class="form-control input catix" disabled="${show}" value="${configuracaoSistemaInstance?.enderecoServicosCatix}"/>
```

After i set it disabled through JQuery

```
$('.catix').each(function(){
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        });
```

I send a request to the controller, i want that the saved instance get 'null' in the field i just disabled, but it keep the last value.

Comment: please show us some of your code.  especially the controller part you are talking about.  and maybe what you tried already.

Comment: Just reset the field to its original, last value?

Comment: Yeah the original value, before calling update.

Comment: That was a suggestion, not a question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. Restore the original value when disabling the field. The original value can be stored as a data attribute of the input field itself or in a hidden field.

Add a data attribute to your input element to store the original value:

```
<g:textField name="enderecoServicosCatix" class="form-control input catix" disabled="${show}" data-originalvalue="${configuracaoSistemaInstance?.enderecoServicosCatix}" value="${configuracaoSistemaInstance?.enderecoServicosCatix}"/>
```

Then restore the original values when disabling:

```
$('.catix').each(function(){
    $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).val($(this).attr('data-originalvalue'));
});
```

(I haven't tested it.)

---

Another way would be to create and pass a new parameter to your controller that would instruct it to ignore all "catix" input when binding the data received from the view. That new parameter would be an hidden field like this:

```
<g:hidden name="catix_disabled" value="false"/>
```

Comment: The second option will do the trick, i already thought about that, but there isn't a way of doing it automatically by grails? I mean, without the need to check the value and set null manually?